# How to document Java Record parameters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, java-14, java-record

How is one supposed to document [Java Record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) parameters? I am referring to the parameters that end up becoming constructor parameters, class fields.

I tried:

```
/**
 * @param name the name of the animal
 * @param age the age of the animal
 */
public record Animal(String name, int age)
{
}
```

but IntelliJ IDEA flags `@param`s as an error. I couldn't find an online example of how this is supposed to work. The closest discussion I found is https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225055.

I found some [unit](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/8e76f81d057a#l302.233) [tests](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/8e76f81d057a#l305.81) in the JDK that seem to imply this should be working. Perhaps this is an IDE bug?

I am using OpenJDK 14+36-1461, IDEA 2020.1.

I filed a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238925) against IDEA just in case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### IntelliJ Bug / Missing Feature

Using the in-built JDK tool for `javadoc` with the version `14-ea` and above, I could easily generate Javadoc for a `record`.

[image]

The command used for the same is \

```
/jdk-14.jdk/.../javadoc --release=14 --enable-preview .../src/main/java/.../CityRecord.java
```

So this would certainly be something missing in IntelliJ. (Since the 'Add Javadoc' option also doesn't include the components.)

I must add from the IntelliJ development point of view, of course as a *preview feature* prioritizing the work dedicated towards it to such an extent is also a call that must be taken carefully.

---

**Update**: I could verify that this has been fixed with the latest update from IntelliJ:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 Preview (Community Edition)
Build #IC-202.7319.5, built on September 1, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 x86_64
```

Comment: Update - Apparently, [the bug reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238925) by the asker is accepted to be Fixed on the tracker.

Comment: Update , the bug appears to be Fixed in build 202.3267, current 201.8538.31 was released on 7 July and java doc still does not work on record. I will try the 2020.2 EAP to validate if fixed.

Comment: Cannot say anything about IntelliJ but @param doesn't work in Eclipse either. What works in Eclipse is to add JavaDoc comments to the individual parameter/attribute declarations:
`record MyRecord { /** JavaDoc for a */ String a, ... }`

Comment: Works in IntelliJ 2023

Answer (score 1):

You can also override the generated record methods and provide documentation on them:

```java
public record Animal(String name, int age) {

  /**
   * The name of the animal
   *
   * @return the name
   */
  public String name() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the age of the animal
   *
   * @return the age
   */
  public int age() {
    return age;
  }
}
```

It's important to remember that this is an example. If the documentation of your getters is just `@return the method name`, adding a javadoc provides little to no value (besides possibly a requirement imposed by your work environment).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the way the author is documenting constructor parameters in JEP 395 records **is correct**. There was a discussion about this [in openjdk issue](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8225055). If you experience the same behavior in IntelliJ, then you need to update to at least **IntelliJ 2020.2**, where the fix patch was ported.